# How to load all xml mapping files from hibernate.cfg.xml in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose Here I specified one particular test.hbm.xml file. Instead I want to load all hbm.xml files available in my package.I have lots of hbm.xml mapping files. Inastead of specifying each of them, I want to load all of them. How to do it? Is it possible to do load them by hibernate.cfg.xml file?

```
hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:dbUnitTest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SFMFG\;SET SCHEMA SFMFG</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>  
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>  

        <mapping resource="test.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method available in Configuration Class which can be used to add all hbm.xml file exists in a directory tree programatically.

```
     /**
     * Read all mapping documents from a directory tree.
     * <p/>
     * Assumes that any file named <tt>*.hbm.xml</tt> is a mapping document.
     *
     * @param dir The directory
     * @return this (for method chaining purposes)
     * @throws MappingException Indicates problems reading the jar file or
     * processing the contained mapping documents.
     */
    public Configuration addDirectory(File dir) throws MappingException {
        metadataSources.addDirectory( dir );
        return this;
    }
```

You can use this method to get sessionFactory

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().addDirectory(new File("")).configure().buildSessionFactory()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you won't be able to do this in XML (however you may wanna check at that again)

But still, you can get the desired result when you create your `SessionFactory` object.

This is a solution to add all `*.hbm.xml` files listed under test folder `com/hbmfiles` programatically:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.configure("/com/persistence/hibernate.cfg.xml");

        File[] files = new File("com/hbmfiles").listFiles();

        for(File file : files) {
            if(file.toString().endsWith("hbm.xml")) 
                configuration.addResource(file);
        }

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

*N.B.: The above code is not compiled, but you will get the desired result for sure.*